# What is the best practice of OO design for sharing a method between different classes that refers to the class specific attribute

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

For example, I want class A and class B to share a common method do_something(), but inside the method, it refers to some_attr which varies based on class A or class B.

```
class A:
    ...
    some_attr = 1
     ...

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
           ....
           cls.some_attr...
           ...

class B:
    ...
    some_attr = 2
    ...

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
           ....
           cls.some_attr...
           ...
```

I also want to be able to easily extend the class by just changing the some_attr, without touching the do_something() method.

```
class C(B):
     ...
     some_attr = 3
     ...
```

I don't want C to inherit anything from A, that's why I can't let B inherit A and then let C inherit B.

Is there a better solution than defining an abstract class to store do_something() method and set some_attr to None?

Comment: what are you doing with `some_attr`? can you be more specific about what `do_something` does?

Comment: you ask for oop-best-practices - excluding inheritance? is there a specific reason you don't want to use that? (or you just don't want to inherit from `A` but would be fine inheriting from a different parent class?)

Comment: You can have an abstract class than contains the mutual functionality which can be extended to both the classes. This seems to be the best solution for this.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov, for example, my class represents an Excel worksheet, some_attr is the actual worksheet object, do_something is extracting data from worksheet object. So different classes have different worksheet objects, but extracting data from those objects is same for all.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, I'm currently using a parent class to store the common method and inherit from there, as 101 mentioned below. But just don't feel very confident that it's the best practice for such scenario.

Comment: if i understand your example correct - why not make the 'actual worksheet' an instance attribute (`self.worksheet`) - and have one class only (if indeed the extraction function is the same)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an abstract or base class that holds only things you want in common, e.g.:

```
class Base(object):
    some_attr = None

    @classmethod
    def do_something(cls):
       cls.some_attr...
```

And inherit from that.

Comment: This is what I currently use in my code. But setting some_attr to None seems not ideal. Because I ended up with a lot of attributes set to None, or empty string in the Base class, and soon lost track of what really needs to be defined in Base. Not defining some_attr in the Base class makes more sense to me and seems also to work, except that my Pycharm doesn't like it. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: You don't have to define `some_attr` etc in the base class, it's simply what's typically done for convenience. You can also force methods to be abstract using the [abc module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) so that the child class must override them.

Comment: Thank you! abc module seems to be the way to go if I really don't want to set to a dummy value.